# Error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" receiving JSON data

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ajax

I'm learning how to get JSON data into a table. My table:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>V.0.0.31</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(function() {


   var people = [];

   $.getJSON(("http://my address:3000/m_info/", { mode: 'no-cors'}), function(data) {
       $.each(data, function(i, f) {
          var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.n_m + "</td>" +
           "<td>" + f.name_m + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.address + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.full_name_of_direcor + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.phone_number + "</td>" + "</tr>"
           $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
     });

   });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
   <table id= "userdata" border="2">
  <thead>
                <th>Number mine</th>
                <th>Name mine</th>
                <th>Adress</th>
                <th>Full name of the director</th>
                <th>Phone number</th>
        </thead>
      <tbody>

       </tbody>
   </table>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Just in case, I'll indicate how I get JSON data.

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: '',
  host: 'address',
  database: '',
  password: '',
  port: 5432,
})

const getMinfo = (request, response) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM mine_info', (error, results) => {
       if (error) {
         throw error
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows)
     })
}

const createRow = (request, response) => {
    const { n_mine, name_mine, adress, full_name_of_direcor, phone_number } = request.body
  
    pool.query('INSERT INTO mine_info (n_m, name_m, address, full_name_of_direcor, phone_number) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *', [n_m, name_m, address, full_name_of_direcor, phone_number], (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error
      }
      response.status(201).send(`User added with ID: ${results.rows[0].id}`)
    })
  }

module.exports = {
    getMinfo,
    createRow,
}
```

I can also state with accuracy that the JSON data is available at this link

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGIel.jpg)

But I get an error as if I'm following a completely different link
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ9ui.png)

I tried to change the link, which didn't help. I also did a local JSON file to check whether it takes data in principle.

Comment: You can't fetch JSON data with `mode: 'no-cors'`